# Add pagination on display post wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using the below code to list the posts but there are more than 200 posts so i want to add pagination at the end.

```
<?php
        // the query
        $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'category_name' => 'Reports',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
        ));
        ?>

        <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-12 event_col">
                            <div class="col-md-2 event_date">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span><?php echo the_post_thumbnail(null, 'medium');?></span></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7 event_venue">
                                <div class="titl">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: WP has a variety of pagination functions: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: ok so where to add in the above code? can you please send me the code with pagination. Any pagination will work. Thanks.

Comment: I encourage you to try yourself. The documentation link in my previous comment has full working examples you can copy and try.

Comment: Hi, thats not working. Can you please let me know how to add "Load More" function.